# How to ensure variable coherency between multiple tabs with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs front-end that display a menu only if the user is logged. When I logout, I update my variable `isLogged` to false: it hides the menu.

If I open my frontend in multiple tabs (already logged), I logout in one of them: my menu is hidden in the tab in which I log out, but, in all other tabs, my logged-only menu is still here.

I have a function `checkIfIsLogged` which checks if a token is stored (which proves that the user is logged) and if not, pass `isLogged` variable to false. I can use this function in order to keep the coherency and update  `isLogged` in any tabs but what's the best practice? Run it periodically? Only when the user focus on the tabs? Other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of continuously checking the storage, you can put an event listener on localStorage changes and handle them properly.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {  
  if (event.key === 'token'&& !event.newValue) {
      console.log('Logged out from another tab!');
      // do whatever you need after logout
  }
});
```

So when somebody changes localStorage from another tab - this event will be fired.
Note, that event is fired on all tabs except the one where change was done.
You can read more about StorageEvent [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

https://coderwall.com/p/bmzw8g/cross-tab-communication-using-localstorage

`When a value is written to localStorage key, a storage event gets fired in all tabs (that are open on the same domain) except the one that did the writing. This can be exploited to communicate messages across tabs.`

Here's the api:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent

`The StorageEvent is fired whenever a change is made to the Storage object (note that this event is not fired for sessionStorage changes). This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need